# How do I print to a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm working on a perl script that is supposed to output information to a command line but I would like to be able to create a file and print the information onto it.
Basically I want to replace the print statement with another statement that would write and store the information in a file instead.

```
foreach(my $i=0; $i < scalar(@netstat_array); $i++)
    {
     if($netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"} eq $protocol_name_input)
         {
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"};
             print ";";
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"local_address"};
             print ";";
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"port_number"};
             print ";";
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"listening_device"};
             print ";";
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"process_identifier"};
             print ";";
             print $netstat_array[$i]{"process_name"};
             print "\n";
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Comment: `perl your_script.pl > your_file.txt` ?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I/O even.  `perlintro`: 20 minutes of required reading.

Comment: You might also like `print join ';', $netstat_array[$i]{protocol_name}, $netstat_array[$i]{local_address}, ... ;`. And while we are at it, if you are trying to make a CSV file, you should take a look at http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV

Comment: Or even - `print join ';', @{$netstat_array[$i]}{qw[protocol_name local_address ...]};`.

Answer (score 3):

Three alternatives:

1. Print to a new filehandle.

   Open the file outside of your loop.

   ```
   open my $out_fh, '>', 'your_file_name' or die $!;
   ```

   Then change all of your print statements to print to the new filehandle.

   ```
   print $out_fh $netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"}; #etc...
   ```
2. Change the default filehandle.

   Open the filehandle as in the previous example. But then call [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to change the filehandle that `print` uses by default.

   ```
   select $out_fh;
   ```

   That way you don't need to change your `print` statements at all.
3. Don't change your code at all. Use your operating system's I/O redirection features to redirect `STDOUT` to a file when you call your program.

   ```
   $ ./your_program.pl > your_output_file
   ```

**Update:** Just thought of a nicer way to do all of your printing.

```
my @cols = qw[protocol_name local_address port_number
              listening_device process_identifier process_name];

foreach my $i (0 .. $#netstat_array) { # much easier to understand
  if($netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"} eq $protocol_name_input) {
    # Hash slices are cool!
    print join ';', @{$netstat_array[$i]}{@cols};
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using an ordered list but the slash thing instead?

Comment: I was too lazy to work out how to construct an ordered list where every item has multiple paragraphs. Feel free to edit :-)

Comment: Done. It's just a bunch of additional spaces really. :)

Answer (score 0):

`print` prints to a file handle, which, if not given explicitly, is STDOUT by default.

`print "Hello, world!"` is the same as `print STDOUT "Hello, world!"`. Note that there is no comma between STDOUT and the string to be printed (so called indirect object syntax).

You can create your own file handle with `open(my $fh, '>', 'output.txt');` and use `print $fh "Hello, world!"` instead of `print "Hello, world!"`.

Comment: Please do not use global file handles. Use a lexical filehandle `$fh` instead.

Comment: You should also always check for failure after the attempted `open`: `open my $fh, '<', 'filename.txt' or die $!;` Replace `die` with `warn` if you want to handle the problem gracefully.

Answer (score -1):

use this subroutine it's an easy way

```
sub save {
    my ($file,$item) = @_;
    open(SAVE,">>".$file);
    print SAVE $item."\n";
    close(SAVE);
}
```

just use `save($file_to_save,$text_to_save);`
in you exemple you can print `$netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"}`
in a 1.txt file like this :

```
save ("1.txt",$netstat_array[$i]{"protocol_name"});
```

Comment: Please don't use bareword filehandles. And **always** check the return value from `open`. Oh, and why assume that the user only wants to print one items? Why not `my ($file, @items) = @_` ?